# Hugo Reference Error When Accessing Subfolder's File

Tags: hugo

Everything is working when I run locally, but when I deploy I'm getting this error.

I have a folder structure like this:

- Root

  - content
  - project

    - [some_project]
    - my_post_markdown.md

      - [some_sub_folder]
      - [another_sub_folder]

        - index.html
        - Build
        - [some_file.js]

I am able to get `my_post_markdown.md` to render and link to `[some_sub_folder]/[another_sub_folder]/index.html`.

The problem is that `index.html` relies on `Build/[some_file.js]` and is unable to load it. I'm seeing the folowing in my console

The real errors I see are:

> Loading failed for the  with source “https://www.greghilston.com/project/global_game_jam_2019/web/Build/UnityLoader.js“. web:10:1
>
> ReferenceError: UnityLoader is not defined[Learn More]

How can I get the sub folder's file accessible by my `html` file?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps outlined in this blog post:

https://medium.com/@aboutin/unity-github-pages-and-file-organization-575ce082b591

1. Put index.html and all files in /Build and /TemplateData into the same directory.
2. Modify index.html to remove “Build/” and “TemplateData/” from all file locations.